# Df groupby set comparison

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a list of words that I want to test for anagrams. I want to use pandas so I don't have to use computationally wasteful for loops. Given a .txt list of words say:

"acb"
"bca"
"foo"
"oof"
"spaniel"

I want to put them in a df then group them by lists of their anagrams - I can remove duplicate rows later.

So far I have the code:

```
import pandas as pd

wordlist = pd.read_csv('data/example.txt', sep='\r', header=None, index_col=None, names=['word'])
wordlist = wordlist.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
wordlist['split'] = ''
wordlist['anagrams'] = ''

for index, row in wordlist.iterrows() :
    row['split'] = list(row['word'])

wordlist = wordlist.groupby('word')[('split')].apply(list)
print(wordlist)
```

How do I groupby a set so it knows that

```
[[a, b, c]]
[[b, a, c]]
```

are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `sorted` `list`s:

```
df['a'] = df['word'].apply(lambda x: sorted(list(x)))
print (df)

      word                      a
0      acb              [a, b, c]
1      bca              [a, b, c]
2      foo              [f, o, o]
3      oof              [f, o, o]
4  spaniel  [a, e, i, l, n, p, s]
```

Another solution for find anagrams:

```
#reverse strings
df['reversed'] = df['word'].str[::-1]

#reshape
s = df.stack()
#get all dupes - anagrams
s1 = s[s.duplicated(keep=False)]
print (s1)
0  word        acb
   reversed    bca
1  word        bca
   reversed    acb
2  word        foo
   reversed    oof
3  word        oof
   reversed    foo
dtype: object

#if want select of values by second level word
s2 = s1.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'word']]
print (s2)
0    acb
1    bca
2    foo
3    oof
dtype: object
```

Comment: So in your original example, how come I can't use join() on the list? It doesn't want to let me!

Comment: Yes, it is not possible, need convert to tuples. So use `df['a'] = df['word'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(list(x))))`

Comment: Sorry I'm really confused - this doesn't work either: anaglist = wordlist['anagrams'] = wordlist['word'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(list(x))))
    wordlist['anagrams'] = ''.join(anaglist)

Comment: I think I get it, use `df['word'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(list(x))))`

Comment: That's awesome! :D

Comment: Thanks - I'm still running into problems but with a separate issue - if you want to take a look it's here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325601/pandas-keeps-converting-strings-to-int - all credit to your solution